# conditional statement for media query on tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, tailwind-css

How can i put this

```
${window.scrollY > 0 ? " bg-slate-50" : ""}
```

Conditional statement only for medium or large screens on tailwind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${window.scrollY > 0 ? "max-md:bg-slate-50" : ""}`

you can also get the reference from the documentation of Tailwind for more info:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-single-breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by adding this in your code:

`className={md:${window.scrollY > 0 ? "bg-slate-50" : "bg-transparent"}}`

Thats tailwind way of doing it. otherwise you can always write the custom css.

Note Please make sure to include the required variant in your `tailwind.config.js` if it's not already enabled:

```
 module.exports = {
      variants: {
        backgroundColor: ['responsive', 'hover', 'focus'],
        // ... other configurations
      },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<div className={`md:${window.scrollY > 0 ? " bg-slate-50" : "bg-transparent"}`}>
...
</div>
```

You can follow this documentation for more info:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design